# Different initial condition in a recursive formula for Bernoulli numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, bernoulli-numbers

Consider the following recursive equation for $k\ge 1$:
\begin{equation}
 a_k = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{-1}{2k + 1 - 2i} \binom{2k}{2i} a_i \tag{1}.
\end{equation}
If $a_0 = 1$, then $a_k$ is the $2k$-th Bernoulli number $B_{2k}$.
I want to prove that if $a_0 = 0$, then $a_k$ is $(2^{2k}-1)B_{2k}$. Does anybody have any idea? Thanks!

I checked the fact on the computer for big $k$. Every proof I attempt seems to lead to heavy computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider *arbitrary* $a_0$, rewrite the recurrence as $$\frac{1}{(2n)!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2}{(2n+1-2k)!}\frac{a_k}{(2k)!}\qquad(n>0)$$ and introduce the generating function $A(a_0,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{2n}/(2n)!$; then
\begin{align*}
\cosh z\underbrace{{}-1+2a_0}_{\text{to fix }n=0}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2}{(2n+1-2k)!}\frac{a_k}{(2k)!}\\&=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a_k}{(2k)!}\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1-2k)!}\\\color{gray}{[n=m+k]}\quad&=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a_k z^{2k}}{(2k)!}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2m}}{(2m+1)!}=2A(a_0,z)\frac{\sinh z}{z}.
\end{align*}
Now, if we put $a_0=1$ and $a_0=0$, we obtain $$A(1,z)=\frac{z}{2}\frac{e^z+1}{e^z-1},\qquad A(0,z)=\frac{z}{2}\frac{e^z-1}{e^z+1},$$ and it remains to check $A(0,z)=A(1,2z)-A(1,z)$, which is done easily.

Comment: Great, thanks! I would not have come up with this.

Comment: To be fully correct, one should also check that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[2n]{|a_n/(2n)!|} < \infty$ for the resummation to be valid. Right?

Comment: @Pavel: Yes, and a justification goes by "tracing back" (or "replaying"). The *function* we have obtained finally *has* a power series with a positive radius of convergence (in fact it is at least $\pi$). So the whole derivation is valid with *this* power series in place of $A(a_0,z)$. And the power series is unique.